# How to remove table column based on content?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="50">
                <img title="Image1" 
                     src="images/image1.png" onclick="dosomething()">
            </td>
            <td width="50">
                <img title="Image2" src="images/image2.png" 
                     onclick="dosomethingelse()">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to delete the `<td>` that contains Image1.  I know in jQuery I can delete the image itself with

```
$( "img[title='Image1']" ).remove();
```

But I want to nuke the containing `<td>` and its width as well to collapse the table as if that image and its column were never there...

Is there a way to back up to the containing element from `$("img[title='Image1']")`?  Or do I need to loop over the whole table (which could be huge) and search for this?

Comment: Haven't done Jquery, but wild guess would be .parent().remove();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do `$("img[title='Image1']").parent().remove();`. That would remove the cell containing the image (assuming the image is always the direct descendant of the cell).

Answer (score 2):

I would go with

```
$("img[title='Image1']").closest('td').remove();
```

or like the others mention:

```
$("img[title='Image1']").parent().remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

[`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) should do it.

```
$("img[title='Image1']").parent().remove();
```

Although personally I'd slap an ID on the image and use:

```
var toremove = document.getElementById('imageid').parentNode;
toremove.parentNode.removeChild(toremove);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/):

```
$( "img[title='Image1']" ).parent().remove();
```

From the docs:

> **.parent( [selector ] )**
> Get the parent of each element in the current set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "img[title='Image1']" ).parent().remove();
```

This should do what you want..

Answer (score 1):

This will remove the column based on the clicked image.

```
$('table img').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('td').remove();
});
```